# Netbeans project files in iCloud

Tags: netbeans, icloud

I'm trying to move my Netbeans Java projects to iCloud on a Mac running Sonoma, but I can't find any way to refer to iCloud locations from Netbeans' Open Project dialogs.
Is there any way to do this? Thanks